# Python loop with default value otherwise infinite

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a loop which runs n-times where:

1. 'n' can be changed freely
2. 'n' should have a default value when no value is passed
3. 'n' should run forever when wanted

My current code looks like this:

```
n = raw_input('number of runs: ')       # Get user input for 'n'
if n == '':                             # Empty input -> run the loop 1000 times (condition 2)
    a = 1000                            # Default value
elif n == 'oo':                         # Run the loop forever
    a = 9000                            # This value isn't important could be 1 aswell see while statement
else:
    a = n                               # Run the loop for the value provided in raw_input
i = 1
while i <= int(a):
    if n == 'oo': 
        a += 1                          # If n=∞, increment 'a' after each iteration so the loop never stops
    print i                             # Print 'i' to see if everything works like expected
    i += 1
```

How can I make this code more elegant (I feel like there is an easier way)? How can I make my loop (for n='oo') stop whenever I want without using a keyboard interrupt?

Comment: You can use a default parameter in a function if you want to run it a default number of times. Something like: `def loop(n=1000):`

Comment: Yes you are right and I knew about this but I don't want to use a function in this case.

Comment: "How can I make my loop (for n='oo') stop whenever I want without using a keyboard interrupt?", so what do you want to use to indicate when you want it to stop?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for`-loop, and different iterables:

```
from itertools import count

n = raw_input('number of runs: ')
if n == '':     #empty input-> run the loop 1000 times
    counter = xrange(1, 1001)
elif n == 'oo': #run the loop forever
    counter = count(1)
else:
    counter = xrange(1, int(n)+1)   #otherwise run the loop for the value provided above
for i in counter:
    print i    #print i to see if everything works like expected
```

Comment: This seems to do the job better than my solution. Any idea how I could implement a termination condition when running the infinite loop?

Comment: @A.Bogner `if my_condition: break`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = raw_input('Enter value for a: ')

try:
   a = int(a)
except:
   if a != 'oo':
       a = 10000

if a == 'oo':
   while True:
       print "infinite"
       pass
else:
   while a != 0:
       # do something
       print a
       a = a - 1
```